# How to time voices right PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to make a custom voice sentences reader. I wrote this code which basically takes a word make it a letter for letter sound but when I type in "Hello" for example it doesn't say the word correctly but instead meshes it up like for instance hello becomes hlelo as spoken voice. How can I fix this?

```php
<?php

  $voiceinput = "hello";
  $voicelength = strlen($voiceinput);
  $lengthforloop= $voicelength - 1;

  echo "<div id='word'>$voiceinput</div>";


for ($x = 0; $x <= $lengthforloop; $x++) {

  $getletterforprocessing = $voiceinput[$x];

    echo '<audio id="player" autoplay>
    <source src="voices/'.$getletterforprocessing.'.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio> ';

  ?>
```

Comment: The HTML that is being generated has nothing in it to control the order in which the sounds are played. Remove the autoplay, and add JavaScript that will play the sounds one after another.

Comment: please elaborate

Answer (score -1):

If you want to speak words, you should not use the spelling of a word, you should use IPA code. E.g. "through", there are many characters you do not say.
"θruː" is the correct IPA code for that word.